# Specman method returns sized list

Tags: specman

I want to define a method that returns a sized lists.
E.g.

```
my_method(): list of my_struct is { ... };
```

will obviously return a list of unknown size. The online documentation has no syntax definition for a sized list as return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List sizes are specified like:

```
my_list : list of int;
keep my_list.size() == 4;
```

You could wrapper such a list in a template struct and constrain the list inside the struct to a number like this:

```
<'

struct my_struct {
    data : int;
};

template struct FourElemWrpr of ( <first'type> ) {
    d : list of <first'type>;
    keep d.size() == 4;
};

extend sys {
    foo() : FourElemWrpr of int is {
        gen result;
        print result.d;
    };
    run() is also {
        var wrpr := foo();
        print wrpr.d;
    };
};

'>
```

When run on Specman 10, this yields:

```
Welcome to Specman Elite 
[...]

Generating the test with Pgen using seed 1...

Starting the test ...
Running the test ...
  result.d =
0.      -208970122
1.      -1768025704
2.      -65377588
3.      -723567746
  wrpr.d =
0.      -208970122
1.      -1768025704
2.      -65377588
3.      -723567746
No actual running requested.
Checking the test ...
Checking is complete - 0 DUT errors, 0 DUT warnings.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a struct field of a list type, you can also specifiy its size as follows:

```
struct list_wrapper {
    my_list[4]: list of int;
};
```

which can be used instead of:

```
struct list_wrapper {
    my_list: list of int;
    keep my_list.size() == 4;
};
```

This syntax is only available for fields. Not for local variables, methods return types, etc.

Also, notice that it's not a "fixed sized" list as it could seem. The declared size (4 in the above example) only means the **initial** size. Once created, elements can be added, removed, etc. like with any other list.

There is one important difference between the [*size*] notation and using the constraint. While a constraint only takes effect for **generated** fields when the containing struct is generated, the [*size*] notation takes effect also for fields of structs created by **new**, or for non-generateable fields.